# Charles proxy in non debuggable flavour of Android app

Tags: android, charles-proxy, network-monitoring

First of all let me clarify that I know that this is a very bad practice and I will not push this change into my production code. But sometimes we need to debug some changes in non debuggable flavour of my application but all the https urls are failing with the following error

`Client SSL handshake failed: An unknown issue occurred processing the certificate (certificate_unknown)`

I have used the following network config files and added in my manifest file. This is working in debuggable flavour of the app but still not working in non-debuggable flavour.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Is there any way I can use charles to monitor my network calls in the non-debuggable flavour of the android app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one works for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-nougat-charlesing-ssl-network-efa0951e66de)

Answer (score 0):

When creating your release build that needs to debug using Charls, In the Manifest inside the application context. please add `android:debuggable="true"` after that try to build your release build and try to debug using Charls.
I have not tried this but this might work. According to the following link.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Comment: I don't wan't to make my app debuggable. I mentioned in the question that I want to debug the debuggable question.